# JFrame update when data change

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How do I update a `JFrame` display when data in my program changes?

A bit of context. I'm currently working on some sort of Ant Colony simulation (it's not a school project. Well... not MY school ;p (I'm not helping someone either, I'm just doing it for fun))

In that simulation, I try to display a map of the current state of the simulation, displaying the position of the food, ant, colony, rocks...

What I'm doing currently: I have "two maps". Each is a 2d array. The first one contain the ID of each element, the other one contain the icon (at the right position of the array/map) that is shown to the user, and that only display the most important object of that case (For example, if an ant is on the same square than the colony, only the colony will show up).

The data behind each map work fine and contain exactly what I want.

The problem is that, once the simulation start running, my frame is still stuck on cycle 0.

So (for the one that didn't read above), how can I update the frame display when my map data are changed?

Some bits of my current code:
Edit: compilable version with a cheap way to make a value change periodically

My "main"

```
public class FInit {
    public static String[][] textGrid= 
            {{"+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+"},
             {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#", "|"},
             {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
             {"|", " ", " ", " ", "O", " ", "|"},
             {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
             {"|", " ", "#", "O", "©", "O", "|"},
             {"+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+"}};
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        FFenetre fenetre = new FFenetre();
        fenetre.fMapWindows(textGrid.length, textGrid[0].length);
        while(true){
            fenetre.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            if(textGrid[5][4].equals("©")) textGrid[5][4]=" ";
            else textGrid[5][4]="©";
        }
    }
}
```

the other relevant bit:

```
public class FFenetre extends JPanel {  
    public FFenetre test;

    public void fMapWindows(int x, int y){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Carte");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize((x+1)*20, (y+2)*20+5);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        FFenetre test = new FFenetre();
        frame.add(test);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //frame.setContentPane(new FGraphiqueMapIcones());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20);
        g.setFont(font);
        for(int a=0; a<FInit.textGrid.length; a++){
            for(int b=0; b<FInit.textGrid[0].length; b++){
                g.drawString(FInit.textGrid[b][a], (a)*20+5, (b+1)*20);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really know what I was doing after the `@Override` part, as I tried to implement solutions of different people, but none really made to handle what I wanted (not a button nor a mouse movement)

Comment: Side note: creating a new `Font` in `paint` is a bad idea. Create it in your constructor, not your paint method.

Comment: Typically you want to override `paintComponent`, not `paint`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"I tried solution of different people"* What solutions? Link to them. Why did those solutions not work? 3) `while(true){` this is not the way to do animation in Swing. Establish a Swing `Timer` whose action listener calls `repaint()` on action performed.

Comment: .. 4) `public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);` for any `JComponent` such as `JPanel`

Comment: Sorry if I didn't exactly followed the rules ^^'. I'm kinda new to "JFrame" and really new to "listener". For the solutions, there is 1)Too many of them 2)On this site 3)All about listener, but always about action if you press a button or move the mouse, I've fail to find any solution with simple value that change. (They simply not updated my JFrame too, but I thing that's because I didn't adapted them right). For the 'while(true)' it's a place-holder solution. (I'll edit my post to make it compilable right away)

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer` which can be used as your "main loop" so you can update the state of the model and schedule repaints to your component. See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks a lot. The question is now, how do I use that "worker.isDone" to make the repaint occur after the simulation end? Or would it be better to run my repaint just before a new cycle of simulation?